# wso2 esb "api not found" when car deployed with others on partition

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We have a set of REST APIs on WSO2 ESB. Our APIs respond as expected if our .car is the only one deployed. However, we share a partition with multiple teams. When we deploy our .car file with the other .car files, whether locally or on the cloud, our APIs do not seem to get deployed. Any call to them throws an "API Not Found" 404.

We have had multiple sets of eyes on this for two days, but so far no dice. What we tried before posting this question:

1. Checked Jenkins logs to make sure build went OK
2. Checked server logs in Splunk to make sure deployment was successful
3. Double-checked to be sure endpoints were correct
4. Made sure there were no typos in URLs
5. Removed comments from artifact xml files
6. Performed a clean build and install, just in case
7. Downloaded all of the .car files from the partition and mounted them on a developer's machine, and ran them on localhost. We were able to reproduce the issue as long as all the .car files were there, but when we ran our .car by itself, the issue went away, and the APIs worked fine.

Has anyone else seen this? If so, what was the resolution?

Answer (score 1):

We learned that there is a quirk in WSO2 ESB as follows:

If another Synapse API config file has a context that matches a portion of your Synapse API config context, then WSO2 ESB may not find your APIs. The behavior appears to be inconsistent, but it does happen.

For example, suppose both of these Synapse API contexts exist on the same partition:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="API_THEIRS" context="/foo/bar/">

<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="API_MINE" context="/foo/bar/bat">
```

In this case, the ESB may never find the APIs defined in API_MINE, because it when a request comes in for "/foo/bar/{anything}" it will look for a matching resource in API_THEIRS. If the resource is not there, the ESB throws an "API Not Found" error.

That is what happened to us. One of the other teams had a context path that matched the first few steps in our path, so the ESB looked for our resources in there.